# Zsh cannot be customized

Tags: zsh, chmod, oh-my-zsh

I have trouble trying to customize my z shell with OMZ framework and some other plugins. I am in my zsh, but when I tried to `echo $ZSH_THEME`, nothing appears. I am suspecting that the problem has to do with permission, but I don't know a whole lot about `chmod`.

The reason for my suspicion is when every time I log into my shell, I have to source one of the plugins every time I log in `source ./zsh-syntax-highlighting/zsh-syntax-highlighting.zsh` in order for it to show.
Any help would be much appreciated!

EDIT: I also try to add PATH, but it doesn't seem to carry over to the next session.

UPDATE: so I removed .zshrc folder and configured a new .zshrc file. It solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Zsh cannot automatically find which plugins to run, and to tell it to run the plugin when zsh starts, you need to put the source line somewhere in your `~/.zshrc`

Eg. add

```
source ./zsh-syntax-highlighting/zsh-syntax-highlighting.zsh
```

to the end of `./zshrc`

Comment: I had that but it doesn't work :(